# Type mismatch error in VBscript when calling a custom subroutine

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have this subroutine:

```
Sub AssertTrue(condition, success, error)
    If condition Then
        %><div style='color:black'><%=success%></div><%
    Else
        %><div style='color:red'><%=error%></div><%
    End If
End Sub
```

And when I call it like so:

```
AssertTrue IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Empty), "Empty is blank.", "Empty is not blank."
```

using this function:

```
' Determines if a string is null, blank, or filled with whitespace.
' If an array of strings is passed in, the first string is checked.
Function IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)
    If IsArray(str) Then
        If str.Length > 0 Then str = str(0) Else str = Empty
    End If
    IsNullOrWhiteSpace = IsEmpty(str) Or (Trim(str) = "")
End Function
```

Then I get a type mismatch error on the `AssertTrue` call. But VBscriptis a weakly typed language and I don't see where types are getting mixed up - `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` does return a boolean! Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

And yes, I am attempting to create unit tests in VBscript. If there's a better way to do so, please let me know... :)

Comment: What is `str.Length`, don't you mean `Ubound(str)` or if you are checking the length of a string you want `Len(str)`?

Comment: Oh really? Yeah, I'm coming from VB.NET so VBscript is really weird to me. Especailly when calling a nonexistent property of an array results in undefined behavior rather than an error!

Comment: And that was it - wanna post your comment as an answer? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Type Mismatch error is exactly what it says, you are referencing a type incorrectly or not as expected.

The problem is in the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` function call, on this line;

```
If str.Length > 0 Then str = str(0) Else str = Empty
```

caused by referencing a string as an object reference. Strings do not contain properties like object types do so the `str.Length` in the code is causing a Type Mismatch error.

To check the length of a string you should use;

```
Len(str)
```

In this case though you appear to be checking an Array so you should be using;

```
UBound(str)
```